# Move values from range while preserving formulas in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to make a macro that moves values from a range to another, while preserving formulas in the range.

So far I have this:

```
Sub change_fiscal_year()

Sheets("1 Income statement").Range("E1:E23").Value = Sheets("1 Income statement").Range("D1:D23").Value

End Sub
```

It works, but it copypastes the values instead of moving them, so formulas are not preserved. How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sheets("1 Income statement").Range("E1:E23").Formula = Sheets("1 Income statement").Range("D1:D23").Formula
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. Didn't know about .Formula.

Comment: @user1775611 - Glad I could help.